# CefSharp EvaluateScriptAsync always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp

I'm trying to get ahold of financial datapoints stored on a page ("https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/31607/ica-gruppen").

Refining the question a bit.

[image: Chrome console]

Then I'm trying to return the datapoints from the CEFSHARP browser to C#.

```
 const string script = @"(function() 
 {   
    var data = this.Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points;

    return data;
 })();";

browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
{
    var response = x.Result;

    if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
    {
       //Saving the data to a database.
    }
});
```

This return NULL or undefined. Then I tried to check wheter the keys where available at all. Code follows.

```
browser.FrameLoadEnd += testing;

 private void testing(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs args)
    {
        const string scriptet = @"(function() { var body = window; return Object.keys(body) + ' ' + 'Empty'; })();";


        browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(scriptet).ContinueWith(y =>
        {
            var response = y.Result;

            if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
            {
                var onePlusOne = (int)response.Result;

            }

        });
    }
```

I get all the **basic keys** but **NOT a single one related to the page**.

I tried the same in the devtools, running this command:

```
Object.keys(window)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: @amaitland of course

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `ContinueWith` instead of `await`?

Comment: Have you tried returning the array count? `FrameLoadEnd` roughly equates to the `DOM` being loaded, if your page is say rendered dynamically when the `DOM` is loaded then you will need to adapt a different approach.  `ContinueWith` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @amaitland yes I'm trying that now, you can acctually see that two version of the page is rendered. But I lack the data fort the charts.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points that you should consider to solve the problem:

- Wait until the page load completely.
- Wait enough for chart to load data.
- Project fields of data into a new array of a custom object (like you do in linq select)

Then you can get the data from chart:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(
        "https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/31607/ica-gruppen");
    browser.LoadingStateChanged += Browser_LoadingStateChanged;
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(browser);
}

private async void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, 
    LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!e.IsLoading)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        var script = @"
            (function () {
                var data = Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points;
                return Array.from(data, p => ({x:p.x, y:p.y, name: p.name}));
            })();";
        var result = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
        MessageBox.Show($"{((dynamic)result.Result).Count}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is a FrameLoadEnd event handler that doesn't have a corresponding method.